# POST request to create entry is not mapping fields to another collection in Strapi

Tags: http-post, strapi

There are 3 collections, judges,courts and proceedings. While creating a new entry in proceedings which has court, judge, docket(PDF), startdate and endate as their fields i am able to map docket(PDF) using the ID in media library but same doesn't work for court and judges.

Here is my POST call to create a entry:

```
{
    "startdate": "2020-11-10",
    "enddate": "2020-11-25",
    "judge": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "docket": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "court": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

and my response is:

```
{
    "id": 24,
    "startdate": "2020-11-10",
    "judge": {},
    "enddate": "2020-11-25",
    "court": {},
    "created_by": null,
    "updated_by": null,
    "created_at": "2020-11-25T09:11:08.338Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-11-25T09:11:08.360Z",
    "docket": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Agenda-1.pdf",
            "alternativeText": "",
            "caption": "",
            "width": null,
            "height": null,
            "formats": null,
            "hash": "Agenda_1_708f0363ef",
            "ext": ".pdf",
            "mime": "application/pdf",
            "size": 282.99,
            "url": "/uploads/Agenda_1_708f0363ef.pdf",
            "previewUrl": null,
            "provider": "local",
            "provider_metadata": null,
            "created_by": 1,
            "updated_by": 1,
            "created_at": "2020-08-17T14:07:45.656Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-08-17T14:07:45.862Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do i map court and judge fields just like docket?

Comment: Looks like using a "id" itself works...Once strapi restarted the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like that :

```json
{
    "startdate": "2020-11-10",
    "enddate": "2020-11-25",
    "judge": 1,
    "docket": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "court": 1
}
```

I guess you can have more than one `docket` because it’s an array in the output, but for the `judge` and the `court` probably just one. So you can do it like there : https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#create-an-entry

Comment: Thank you. My initial post call itself worked perfectly fine after strapi restarted. Not sure exactly what the issue was.